# How to resolve the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I'm using odoo 11 and i received this error

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison``` when I added the two fields `no_overtime_final` and  `tot_overtime_final` .I don't know where is the problem in my method. I notice if I comment these two fields every thing works fine.  Any idea for help please ?

Code:

```
class attendance_sheet(models.Model):
 _name = 'attendance.sheet'
 employee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Employee', required=True)
 date_from = fields.Date(string="From", required=True, default=time.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))
 date_to = fields.Date(string="To", required=True,
                      default=str(datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=+1, day=1, days=-1))[:10])
 att_sheet_line_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='attendance.sheet.line', string='Attendances',readonly=True,
                                     inverse_name='att_sheet_id')
 state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('confirm', 'Confirmed'),
    ('done', 'Approved')], default='draft', track_visibility='onchange',
    string='Status', required=True, readonly=True, index=True,
    help=' * The \'Draft\' status is used when a HR user is creating a new  attendance sheet. '
         '\n* The \'Confirmed\' status is used when  attendance sheet is confirmed by HR user.'
         '\n* The \'Approved\' status is used when  attendance sheet is accepted by the HR Manager.')
 no_overtime = fields.Integer(compute="calculate_att_data", string="No of After work time", readonly=True, store=True)
 tot_overtime = fields.Float(compute="calculate_att_data", string="Total After work time", readonly=True, store=True)
 no_overtime_final = fields.Integer(compute="calculate_att_data", string="No of Overtime", readonly=True, store=True)
 tot_overtime_final = fields.Float(compute="calculate_att_data", string="Total Overtime", readonly=True, store=True)
 tot_difftime = fields.Float(compute="calculate_att_data", string="Total Diff time Hours", readonly=True, store=True)
 no_difftime = fields.Integer(compute="calculate_att_data", string="No of Diff Times", readonly=True, store=True)
 tot_late = fields.Float(compute="calculate_att_data", string="Total Late In", readonly=True, store=True)
 no_late = fields.Integer(compute="calculate_att_data", string="No of Lates", readonly=True, store=True)
 no_absence = fields.Integer(compute="calculate_att_data", string="No of Absence Days", readonly=True, store=True)
 tot_absence = fields.Float(compute="calculate_att_data", string="Total absence Hours", readonly=True, store=True)
 att_policy_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.attendance.policy', string="Attendance Policy ", required=True)
 payslip_id=fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.payslip',string='PaySlip')
 @api.multi
 def calculate_att_data(self):
    overtime = 0
    no_overtime = 0
    overtime_final = 0
    no_overtime_final = 0
    late = 0
    no_late = 0
    diff = 0
    no_diff = 0
    absence_hours = 0
    no_absence = 0
    for att_sheet in self:

        for line in att_sheet.att_sheet_line_ids:
            # print line.date
            if line.overtime > 0:
                overtime += line.overtime
                no_overtime = no_overtime + 1
            if line.overtime_final > 0:
                overtime_final += line.overtime_final
                no_overtime_final = no_overtime_final + 1
            if line.diff_time > 0:
                if line.status == "ab":
                    no_absence += 1
                    absence_hours += line.diff_time
                else:
                    diff += line.diff_time
                    no_diff += 1
            if line.late_in > 0:
                late += line.late_in
                no_late += 1
        values = {
            'tot_overtime': overtime,
            'no_overtime': no_overtime,
            'tot_overtime_final': overtime_final,
            'no_overtime_final': no_overtime_final,
            'tot_difftime': diff,
            'no_difftime': no_diff,
            'no_absence': no_absence,
            'tot_absence': absence_hours,
            'tot_late': late,
            'no_late': no_late

        }
        att_sheet.write(values)

class attendance_sheet_line(models.Model):
 _name = 'attendance.sheet.line'

 state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('confirm', 'Confirmed'),
    ('done', 'Approved')], default='draft',readonly=True)

 date = fields.Date("Date",readonly=True)
 day = fields.Char("Day",readonly=True)
 att_sheet_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='attendance.sheet', string='Attendance Sheet',readonly=True)
 pl_sign_in = fields.Float("Planned sign in",readonly=True)
 pl_sign_out = fields.Float("Planned sign out",readonly=True)
 ac_sign_in = fields.Float("Actual sign in",readonly=True)
 ac_sign_out = fields.Float("Actual sign out",readonly=True)
 overtime = fields.Float("After work time",readonly=True)
 overtime_final = fields.Float("Overtime",readonly=True)
 worked_time = fields.Float("Worked time",readonly=True)
 late_in = fields.Float("Late In",readonly=True)
 diff_time = fields.Float("Diff Time", help="Difference between the working time and attendance time(s) ",readonly=True)
 note = fields.Text("Note")
 status = fields.Selection(string="Status",
                          selection=[('ab', 'Absence'), ('weekend', 'Week End'), ('ph', 'Public Holiday'),
                                     ('leave', 'Leave'), ],
                          required=False,readonly=True)
 note = fields.Text("Note",readonly=True)
```

```
Traceback

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 944, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/api.py", line 967, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
    KeyError: 8
      File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3109, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3339, in _write
    self.recompute()
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in recompute
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in <dictcomp>
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4785, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 948, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1035, in determine_value
    self.compute_value(recs)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1015, in compute_value
    self._compute_value(records)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1006, in _compute_value
    getattr(records, self.compute)()
    File "/opt/openhrms/addons/hr_attendance_sheet/models/hr_attendance_sheet.py", line 165, in calculate_att_data
    att_sheet.with_context(stop_write_recursion=1).write(values)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3109, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3339, in _write
    self.recompute()
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in recompute
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in <dictcomp>
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4785, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 948, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1035, in determine_value
    self.compute_value(recs)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1015, in compute_value
    self._compute_value(records)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1006, in _compute_value
    getattr(records, self.compute)()
    File "/opt/openhrms/addons/hr_attendance_sheet/models/hr_attendance_sheet.py", line 165, in calculate_att_data
    att_sheet.with_context(stop_write_recursion=1).write(values)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3109, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 3339, in _write
    self.recompute()
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in recompute
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4931, in <dictcomp>
    vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 4785, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 948, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/fields.py", line 1049, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 2653, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 2572, in read
    self.check_access_rights('read')
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/models.py", line 2879, in check_access_rights
    return self.env['ir.model.access'].check(self._name, operation, raise_exception)
    File "<decorator-gen-20>", line 2, in check
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 84, in lookup
    r = d[key]
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/tools/func.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: 1) Paste the full error traceback. Its a lot easier to track the issue that way. 2) Please properly indent your code.

Comment: are you overriding the `write` method in this model? if not, please share the model `attendance.sheet.line` code.

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed my question is updated with the model **attendance.sheet.line**

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse the full error traceback is too long

Comment: why you use two loops to catch record in o2m?

Comment: just remain `for line in self.att_sheet_line_ids:` also can fetch records in o2m.

Comment: He can't directly access the `att_sheet_lind_ids` from `self`, the method is decorated with `@api.multi`, so `self` is a **recordset**

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed what should i do in this case ?

Comment: have you tried to use `att_sheet.with_context(stop_write_recursion=1).write(values)`? and please let me know if you **override** the `write` method.

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed no i don't override the write method

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed it shows the same error even when i try **att_sheet.with_context(stop_write_recursion=1).write(values)**

Comment: we need the traceback to be able to help more, try to post at least the most related part of it. also try to add the `depends` decoration to your method `@api.depends('att_sheet_line_ids')`

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed my question is updated with the traceback

Comment: Try to use the `depends` decoration **@api.depends('att_sheet_line_ids')** and also update the `att_sheet` directly `att_sheet.tot_overtime = overtime`